# Terraform: each.value is object with 5 attributes even after adding 6th and 7th attributes

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-storage-account

I'm trying to add a couple of settings, is_hns_enabled and account_kind, to 2 existing storage accounts while creating a third. The 2 exisint just need the defaults for these settings stated explicitly. Running into the below error for all 3 accounts on both new settings. Heres 1 instance of the error

Error:

```
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on storage.tf line 48, in resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage-account":
│   48:   is_hns_enabled           = each.value["is_hns_enabled"]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 5 attributes
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

The storage account already existed but I need to set this setting explicitly to distinguish it from other accounts. I'm setting it to false, which is already the default.

Terraform:

```
locals {
  containers = merge([
    for account, account_details in var.storage_accounts : {
      for container in account_details.containers :
      "${account}-${container["name"]}" => {
        "name"                 = container["name"]
        "access_type"          = container["access_type"]
        "storage_account_name" = account
      }
    }
  ]...)
  roles = merge([
    for account, account_details in var.storage_accounts : {
      for role in account_details.roles :
      "${account}-${role["objectId"]}" => {
        "storage_account_name" = account
        "objectId"             = role["objectId"]
        "storage_role"         = role["storage_role"]
      }
    }
  ]...)
}


resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage-account" {
  for_each                 = var.storage_accounts
  name                     = substr(replace(lower(each.key), "/\\W|_|\\s/", ""), 0, 24)
  resource_group_name      = var.azure["resource_group_name"]
  location                 = var.azure["location"]
  account_tier             = each.value["account_tier"]
  account_kind             = each.value["account_kind"]
  is_hns_enabled           = each.value["is_hns_enabled"]
  account_replication_type = each.value["account_replication_type"]

  blob_properties {
    versioning_enabled = each.value["versioning_enabled"]
  }
}
```

TF, Storage vars:

```
storage_accounts = {
  acct1 = {
    account_tier             = "Premium"
    account_kind             = "BlockBlobStorage"
    account_replication_type = "RAGRS"
    versioning_enabled       = false
    is_hns_enabled           = false
    roles                    = []
    containers = [
      {
        name        = "container1"
        access_type = "private"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a variable spec file that defines the `storage_accounts` "type" explicitly. I didn't know the file existed but I needed to conform to it.

Comment: Try to check for the first non-null value in `is_hns_enabled`. Did you try like that? @sam

Answer (score 1):

> The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.

***After a workaround on this, I found the below approaches:***

*Approach-1:*

You can include `coalesce()` function. The function [coalesce()](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/coalesce) in terraform returns the first non-null value from its arguments. So, if `each.value["is hns enabled"]` is null or undefined, the default value of `false` will be used instead.

```bash
is_hns_enabled = coalesce(each.value["is_hns_enabled"],false)
```

After making few changes, your code looks like below.

```bash
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage-account" {
  for_each                 = var.storage_accounts
  name                     = substr(replace(lower(each.key), "/\\W|_|\\s/", ""), 0, 24)
  resource_group_name      = "Jahnavi"
  location                 = "eastus"
  account_tier             = each.value["account_tier"]
  account_kind             = each.value["account_kind"]
  is_hns_enabled           = coalesce(each.value["is_hns_enabled"],false)
  account_replication_type = each.value["account_replication_type"]

  blob_properties {
    versioning_enabled = each.value["versioning_enabled"]
  }
}
```

*Approach-2:*

Alternatively, if you are trying to get the existed storage accounts and set the required properties, obtain the existed ones using `data` block.

```bash
data "azurerm_storage_account" "example"{
name = "storageaccount"
location="eastus"
}
```

*Terraform is successfully initialized and configuration validation is success.*

[image]

[image]